# jPlayer not playing files in some browsers

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm building a website with a music player, I'm using jPlayer.
Every song is in both mp3 and ogg format in my playlist. 
I'm working on localhost, visual studio 2010 dev server.

- Chrome - Plays fine
- Firefox - Does not play but calls the right file on the server
- Opera - Plays fine
- Safari (Windows) - Plays fine
- IE9 - Plays fine
- IE8/7 - Do not do anything

since jPlayer.js and jplayer.swf are in the same folder I set swfPath = "" ; I /also/tried/absolute/path but did not change anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I got it to work since! I think the problem was related to ASP.NET Routing because as soon as I moved jplayer.swf to the root of the site it worked in all browsers!

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but I came across this while stuck on this same problem. It turned out that the Flash player I installed to make jplayer run on Firefox is not valid for IE8, so I went to Adobe's site to test my flash installation, downloaded the recommended version and it works fine across both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If both files are in the same folder, e.g. both are in the Scripts `http://example.com/Scripts/`, then use `swfPath="/Scripts"`.  Use firebug's Net tab to monitor what is being requested and make sure it is loading correctly.
  As far as playing locally, you might have to adjust your Flash Settings: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html

Comment: Hey I got it to work since! I think the problem was related to ASP.NET Routing because as soon as I moved jplayer.swf to the root of the site it worked in all browsers!

Comment: I had the same exact problem. I moved the jplayer.swf to the root and it worked perfect. Thanks for this!